# Получить имя работающей activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Есть service, который с определенной периодичностью опрашивает имя activity и выводит его в лог. Смысл задачи в том, что если выбрать например VLC, то в логах должно появиться VLC, если mxplayer, то mxplayer. Таймер реализован, но все время выводится в лог имя исходного activity. Понимаю, что вопрос скорее всего не сложный и не должен составить труда, но хоть подскажите в каком направлении копать и искать решение. Вот пример сервиса.

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyService extends Service {
    Timer timer;
    int t=0;
    public MyService() {
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("myLogs", "onStartCommand");
        try {
            someTask();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("myLogs", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    void GoTimeService()
    {
        Log.d("myLogs", "Создание таймера");
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTaskService(),100,1000); //Создался шедулер
    }

    class MyTimerTaskService extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
// Вот сюда будет вставлена функция, показывающая какое приложение запущено.
//Если есть подсказки как это узнать буду признателен.
        }
    }

    void someTask() throws InterruptedException {
        Log.d("myLogs",getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    GoTimeService();
            }
        }).start();    }
}
```

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите - опишите задачу подробнее, покажите код, который работает не правильно и поясните как по-вашему он должен работать.

Comment: Каждую секунду происходит работа шедулера и вызов MyTimerTaskService. Не удалось пока что отыскать, есть ли возможность узнать какое приложение у меня запущено. В дальнейшем хочу поставить ребенку на мобилку приложение, и если он много времени будет проводить за просмотром роликов или фильмов, то выводить ему сообщение, что пора бы взяться за уроки, а не тратить время попусту.

Comment: Следить за работой чужих приложений не простая задача на Андроиде. Попробуйте ответы с en-SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться.